# How to add rows data if the row has same data in table (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My table is like this

```
S.No.   Name    Amount
1       Mike    200
2       Jason   150
3       Mike    100
4       Andy    300
5       Jason   200
```

I want to show it like this (by adding rows)

```
S.No.   Name    Amount
1       Mike    300
2       Jason   350
3       Andy    300
```

My code is -

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% Data.where(:from_user => current_user.id).each_with_index do |tc, index| %>
      <% begin %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=index+1%></td>
            <td><%=User.find(tc.to_user).full_name%></td>
            <td><%=tc.amount%></td>
        </tr>
      <% rescue %>
      <% next %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How to add the amount if the name field is same using Ruby on Rails ?

Answer (score 1):

Editing the answer with the schema, data & code.

Here is the table schema & records

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
| id | full_name | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Gowtham   | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | Mike      | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | Jason     | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 | Andy      | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+

mysql> select * from data;
+----+--------------+------------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | from_user_id | to_user_id | amount | created_at | updated_at |
+----+--------------+------------+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 |            1 |          2 |    200 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 |            1 |          2 |    100 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 |            1 |          2 |    150 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 |            1 |          2 |    200 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  5 |            1 |          3 |    150 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  6 |            1 |          3 |    200 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  7 |            1 |          4 |    300 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+--------------+------------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Now here is the code to find all transfers done by Gowtham to others. You can put this in your controller

```
 @result = Data.where(:from_user_id => 1).select("users.full_name, SUM(data.amount) as total").joins("INNER JOIN users ON users.id = data.to_user_id").group(:to_user_id)
```

You can loop through the @result and display in your views

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @result.each_with_index do |tc, index| %>
      <% begin %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=index+1%></td>
            <td><%=tc.full_name%></td>
            <td><%=tc.total%></td>
        </tr>
      <% rescue %>
      <% next %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I replaced name with User.find(tc.to_user).full_name but it is not defined in the above code. Can you tell me the workaround for it ?

Comment: Understood. This is what you can do  `Data.where(:from_user => current_user.id).select("users.full_name, SUM(data.amount)").joins("INNER JOIN users ON users.id = data.to_user").group(:to_user)`  Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure this will work as this is how I am finding full name <%=User.find(tc.to_user).full_name%> as it is not saved in the User table. I think users.full_name should give error as there is no full name column in it.

Comment: @iCyborg if you can describe your tables users & data schema I might be able to give you an exact answer. The previous comment was based on you have two tables `users` with `id`, `full_name` as columns and table `data` with `from_user`, `to_user`, `amount` as columns

Comment: Sure, I have 2 tables. Users and TransferredAmount. Users can transfer some amount to other users and those transactions get saved into TransferredAmount. The fields in the TransferredAmount Table are Id,From user, To user, Amount. Now with the above code, I am displaying to each user, how much he has transferred to other users on a page. The problem is, if I transferred amount twice to a user, it shows as 2 records where as I want to show it as single record with the sum.

Comment: @iCyborg then the above code works perfectly for your need. It would show you the total amount by adding all the amounts transferred. Re-mentioning the code again `Data.where(:from_user => current_user.id).select("users.full_name, SUM(data.amount)").joins("INNER JOIN users ON users.id = data.to_user").group(:to_user)`. Replace with proper model name

Comment: Unfortunately the code is giving error.  To me, the .group().sum() approach looks to be right but the issue is coming from ".each_with_index do |tc, index|" code. Can you give me the full code to replace this line of code - "<% Data.where(:from_user => current_user.id).each_with_index do |tc, index| %>"

Comment: Since I was putting the code in views which was wrong, now I am putting it in controller though getting "NoMethodError: private method `select' called for". Do I need to put this code in Model ? I ran the code at console and same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for getting name along with its total amount

```
Data.select("name, sum(amount) as amount").group(:name)
```

Comment: Since the code is <% Data.where(:from_user => current_user.id).each_with_index do |tc, index| %>, where should I add the select ? I added it after the where clause but it is giving error as I replaced name with "User.find(tc.to_user).full_name" but tc is not defined.

Comment: Unfortunately this also won't work as my code is     <% Data.where(:from_user => current_user.id).each_with_index do |tc, index| %> and full name and amount are not saved in the table Data so I am calling it like this <%=User.find(tc.to_user).full_name%> only. Any suggestion to solve this issue ?

Comment: To clarify, I have 2 tables. Users and TransferredAmount. Users can transfer some amount to other users and those transactions get saved into TransferredAmount. The fields in the TransferredAmount Table are Id,From user, To user, Amount. Now with the above code, I am displaying to each user, how much he has transferred to other users on a page. The problem is, if I transferred amount twice to a user, it shows as 2 records where as I want to show it as single record with the sum.

Comment: Since I was putting the code in views which was wrong, now I am putting it in controller though getting "NoMethodError: private method `select' called for". Do I need to put this code in Model ? I ran the code at console and same error.

Comment: All the queries part should be there in one method in  model and then you can call that method in controller for fetching data and then represent that data in view and based on your error message I am  sure your model is not an ActiveRecord Object. Please check whether your model on which your are querying .